# Pass optional object without copying it

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, option-type

I encountered the following situation while refactoring old code:

```
// pointers to const are discouraged in our code base
void Do(Foo* exists, Foo* maybe_null) {
  // does not change *exists or *maybe_null
}

int main() {
  // ...
  Do(&foos[i], test_both ? &bars[i] : nullptr);
  // ...
  HighOrderFunction(foos, bars, &Do);
  // ...
}
```

So, `Do` is called with two `Foo` objects of which one definitely exists while the second might not, depending on some outside test. Issues I have with this current code that I am trying to solve:

- The first parameter will never be null so its pointer properties are never used.
- I generally dislike the use of null as an empty value.

So far I came up with three possible solutions, none of which I am completely satisfied with:

- `Do(const Foo&, Foo*)`: The second argument has the same issue as before and now the call syntax is not uniform anymore (`foos[i]` and `&bars[i]`), which might confuse readers.
- `Do(const Foo&, const optional<Foo>&)`: The second `Foo` object has to be copied to construct the optional.
- `Do(const Foo&, optional<const Foo&>)`: Does not actually work since optional of a reference type is disallowed.
- `Do(const Foo&)` and `Do(const Foo&, const Foo&)` overload : Causes problems when I need to pass Do as a function pointer

So, are there any better/cleaner solutions I could use in this situation?

(I am using C++11 with some std additions like optional)

Comment: Overload for both `void Do(const Foo&)` and `void Do(const Foo&, const Foo&)`?

Comment: Is `test_both` a runtime value or a compile-time one?

Comment: @Unimportant Thanks for your comment. I forgot to mention that a pointer to Do needs to be passed to a higher order function now and then, so an overload is not an option. Sorry for the confusion, I added that information to my question.

Comment: @skypjack It's a runtime value.

Comment: @AndreasT How is `HighOrderFunction` defined? Overloading can still be a viable solution indeed.

Comment: @skypjack Indeed I did not think of the possibility of using a functor with overloaded operator().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Do` a functor, not just a function.

```
 struct Do
 {
      void operator()(const Foo &must_be_provided);
      void operator()(const Foo &must_be_provided, const Foo &maybe_unneeded);
 };
```

and then, after implementing the two forms of `Do::operator()`,

```
 void some_function(Do f)
 {
       // assume access to foos and bars here
     if (test_both)   // assume determined at run time
         f(foos[i]);
     else
        f(foos[i], bars[i]);
 }
```

Note that a functor can be passed by value, by reference, or its address can be passed in a pointer (although the syntax for calling the functions changes a little).

Answer (score 2):

If you want an optional reference, you can use `std::reference_wrapper<Foo>`:

```
Do(const Foo&, optional<std::reference_wrapper<const Foo>>)
```

That will avoid copying your objects. And will make the function accept a reference formally.

Sure there's a `reference_wrapper` object created. But it's fairly light. Most implementations just mask a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best execution of my idea to use an optional. I still marked the other answer as accepted because it offers a cleaner solution to the general problem I have.